# Columns in GridView are duplicating after DropDownList Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, autopostback

I would like to learn something about DataTable and GridView. I found piece of code on the Internet:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
   grid1 = new GridView();
   this.form1.Controls.Add(grid1);

   grid1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

   table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
   table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
   table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
   table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

   // Here we add five DataRows.
   table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
   table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
   table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
   table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
   table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

   for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
              BoundField boundfield = new BoundField();
              boundfield.DataField = table.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
              boundfield.HeaderText = table.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
              grid1.Columns.Add(boundfield);
            }
   grid1.DataSource = table;
   grid1.DataBind();
}
```

Result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auXIX.png)

But if I change Selected Value from DropDownList next to Label, that is a result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VkyJ.png)

Why are there more and more columns? Any ideas?

EDIT:
I didnt' write that I would like put data from database into GridView. I will have a SQL query, e.g. "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE id = " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem, so I think it must be executing with every Postback.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are executing your code on every postback, evaluate Page.IsPostBack property in order to check if it's an initial page load or a postback.

You better go to Microsoft Virtual Academy for a while.

Comment: Oh, I didnt' write that I would like put data from database into GridView. I will have a SQL query, e.g. "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem, so I think it must be executing with every Postback.

Comment: Do that on SelectedIndexChanged event of your DropDownList, but it doesn't mean that you should create the columns over and over again. Make a method named "BuildGridView" call it once on Page_Load (IsPostback == true), and make another one named "PopulateGridView" calling it on SelectedIndexChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

put your page load event code inside

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
        // Your logic here
}
```

Every time any control casuses a postback it fires page load event which causes your application to add new gridview to response. Understand how postback works and page life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the grid first then load your data into it.

postback is a better option though. the code is:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                do something
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What the others said - if you're doing this on first load and every single postback you'll get duplicates. The controls in form1 are stored in the view state but you keep creating new ones each time. Encapsulate the code in

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     your code here
}
```